# IBM Containers: cf ic cpi ( copy command ) fails

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

New to IBM Containers, so working through the IBM docs, this page;

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_images_adding_ov.html#container_images_copying

> States: Copy an image from Docker Hub, Bluemix, or your private
>   repository. You can add the copied image to your private repository,
>   without downloading it to your computer first, by running the cpi
>   command.
>
> with the example:

```
cf ic cpi training/sinatra registry.ng.bluemix.net/my_namespace/my_sinatra:new
```

I am running on a  mac, inside a docker command window, so

```
docker images 

REPOSITORY    TAG       IMAGE ID        CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
timdet/docker-whale   latest    a5bb741c4ac2        22 hours ago        274.3 MB
hello-world           latest    0a6ba66e537a        3 months ago        960 B
```

gives me my images both local & on my private dockerhub { timdet}
and

```
cf ic images

REPOSITORY                           TAG    IMAGE ID    CREATED  VIRTUAL SIZE
registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/ibmnode   latest  0482321da78d 6 days ago    433.1 MB
registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/ibmnode   v4      0482321da78d 6 days ago   433.1 MB
```

gives the images in my IBM repository.

From what I understand the command should copy an image from my local / dockerHub into the ibm repository. 
{ I have `cf login` & `cf ic login` ok }

When I run;

```
cf ic cpi timdet/docker-whale registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/ic_tim_donovan_org/docker-whale:new
```

I get the following output;

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 0 : FROM timdet/docker-whale
Pulling repository timdet/docker-whale
Error: image timdet/docker-whale:latest not found
FAILED
```

yet I can see it via docker image and even do a docker pull ok. 
So what am I missing?

The only other item is that my dockerHub image has the private flag on.

Comment: Is this image in your local repository as well? Per the description of the problem is looks like the image you are trying to copy is on your private repository only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well seems I have managed to find out the answer to my own question.

I created my original DockerHub repository as a Private repository .. seems you are now allowed to create one private repository. The downside with keeping your development and testing private is that it cannot then be shared with the likes of IBM Containers. 
I have since created a public DockerHub repository, and was then able to use the copy command to copy an image from DockerHub into my IBM Private repository within Bluemix Containers.